# Parsing a total.txt file by keywords in it

Tags: python, file, parsing

I'm having trouble parsing a file. I have code that parses a file by the word Total: if its value is greater than 20.0 and returns the data. I need to change the search keyword to Tokens eth: with a value greater than 20.0 and output all data between separators ======== and additionally write all sorted values into sort.txt file. I would be grateful for professional help)

Code:

```
outlist = []
flag = False
def dump(list_, flag_):
    if list_ and flag_:
        print('\n'.join(list_))
    return [], False
with open('total.txt') as file:
    for line in map(str.strip, file):
        if line.startswith('='):
            outlist, flag = dump(outlist, flag)
        else:
            tokens = line.split()
            if len(tokens) == 3 and tokens[1] == 'Total:':
                try:
                    flag = float(tokens[2][:-1]) > 20.0
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            outlist.append(line)
dump(outlist, flag)
```

total.txt

```
============
| hafuia
| 0xb34a47885262f9d8673dc77de7b583961134f09fb03620b29d282c32ee6932be
| 0xD0b2612a6eE3111114b43b25322C6F08A251D38D
| Total: 47.62874464666479$
|
|
| Tokens eth:
| 20.608732$ MANA
|
| Protocols cro:
| 17.840052$ VVS Finance
| 8.953779$ V3S Finance
============
| asdf
| 0x72e164aa187feaff7cb28a74b7ff800a0dfe916594c70f141069669e9df5a23b
| 0xC7dFe558ed09F0f3b72eBb0A04e9d4e99af0bd0D
| Total: 22.908481672796988$
|
|
| Tokens eth:
| 22.376087$ SOS
============
| asdf
| 0xbce666bca3c862a2ee44651374f95aca677de16b4922c6d5e7d922cc0ac42a3d
| 0x5870923a244f52fF2D119fbf5525421E32EC006e
| Total: 9.077030269778557$
|
|
| Tokens eth:
| 8.942218$ SOS
============
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please never post picture of textual data, copy paste instead. Picture are very poor medium to exchange textual data.

Comment: can you write the expected output for the input `total.txt` file

Comment: @NiteshTosniwal the output should be the data between the separators ======, provided that the value in the line Tokens eth: is greater than or equal to 20.0

Comment: @EdoAkse These are test pacifiers, I doubt they work at all) this is an example

Comment: @OlegPaslavskiy did I miss something? It seemed you needed the wallets added if the values for the coins on the ETH network was above 20, not when the total listed above that is above 20...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can parse the file.

```py
def parse_output(filename):
    outlist = []
    with open(filename) as file:
        new_block = False
        to_write = False
        lines_arr = []
        for line in map(str.strip, file):
            if line.startswith('======='):
                new_block = not new_block
            if new_block:
                if to_write:
                    outlist.append(lines_arr)
                lines_arr = []
                new_block = False
                to_write = False
            else:
                lines_arr.append(line)
                if 'Total:' in line:
                    num = float(line.split()[-1][:-1])
                    if num > 20:
                        to_write = True

    return outlist


def write_output(outlist, filename):
    for block in outlist:
        for line in block:
            with open(filename, 'a') as out_file:
                out_file.write(line + '\n')

        with open(filename, 'a') as out_file:
            out_file.write('=======' + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_output(parse_output('total.txt'), 'output.txt')
```

I missed the sorted wallet thing. For sorting, while appending array to outlist, you can use another array for order, or prepend the number to array, sort the outputs, and skip first element while writing.

Answer (score 0):

This is written in such a way that it's easy to get fe. the addresses as well. sorting done with a simple lambda function.

```py
from pprint import pprint

wallet_splitter = "============"
wallet_content_start = "Tokens eth:"
wallet_line_start = "|"


with open("totals.txt") as infile:
    wallets = infile.read().split(wallet_splitter)
print(wallets)


wallets_above_20 = []
for wallet in wallets:
    total = 0
    separate = []
    contents = False
    for line in wallet.splitlines():
        if wallet_content_start in line:
            contents = True
        elif contents:
            if "$" in line:
                separate.append(line.replace(wallet_line_start, "").split("$")[0])
                total += float(separate[-1])
            else:
                contents = False
    for amount in separate:
        if float(amount) > 20:
            wallets_above_20.append({
                "total": total,
                "data": wallet
            })

pprint(sorted(wallets_above_20, key = lambda i: i['total'],reverse=True))
```

Comment: This solution works, but time complexity is n^2, and can be further optimized.

Comment: yes, the double complexity is due to the fact that (if I understood OP correctly) he needs to check if the coins on the ETH network are above 20, not the total listed. Your answer would give a false positive if the total in the "Total:" line was above 20, but the calculated total on the ETH network was below 20...

Comment: ah right! it was mentioned: `parses a file by the word Total:`. also in the code snippet provided, he used `Total:` as the keyword. so I used the same. anyways!!

Answer (score 0):

This is another simple extensible approach you can use to achieve what you need. The comments will explain the code.

```
# Create a simple representational object with data for every record.
class RateObject:
    # You can change the delimiter to whatever you want.
    def __init__(self, text_lines: list, delimiter="Tokens eth:"):
        self.text_lines = text_lines
        index = [i for i, x in enumerate(text_lines) if delimiter in x][0]

        # Get the value from delimiter line
        self.value = self._get_value(index)

    # Override this method, to change the way you extract the value. From same line or different line etc. 
    def _get_value(self, delimiter_index: int):
        # Case of Tokens eth:
        value = self.text_lines[delimiter_index + 1]
        value = value.strip()
        # A bad parsing for  numbers, can be improved may be!
        number = "".join([x for x in value if x.isdigit() or x == "."])
        if number:
            return float(number)
        else:
            # Assume 0 for unknown values
            return 0.0

    def __str__(self):
        # Return the lines as it is
        return "".join(self.text_lines)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "".join(self.text_lines)


# read the source file
with open("src.txt", "r") as src:
    line_texts = src.readlines()

# Split the lines into sections, using the delimiter ========
splitters = [index for index, text in enumerate(line_texts) if text == "============\n"]

# Create a list of RateObjects
raw_objects = [RateObject(lt) for lt in [line_texts[splitters[i]:splitters[i + 1]] for i in range(len(splitters) - 1)]]

# Filter the objects, to get only the ones with value > 20
selected_objects = list(filter(lambda x: x.value > 20.0, raw_objects))

# Sort the objects by value
sorted_objects = sorted(selected_objects, key=lambda x: x.value, reverse=True)
# print(selected_objects)
# print(sorted_objects)

# Write the sorted objects to a file
with open("sorted.txt", "w") as dst:
    dst.write("\n".join([str(x) for x in sorted_objects]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple generator-based approach.

```
def items(file):
    """
    Generator to yield items from filename
    whose "Tokens eth:" is above 20.0
    """
    with open(file) as lines:
        item = []
        tokens = 0
        capture = False
        for line in lines:
            if line == "============\n":
                if tokens > 20.0:
                    yield tokens, item
                item = []
                tokens = 0
                continue
            if capture:
                tokens = float(line.strip().split()[-2].rstrip("$"))
                capture = False
            if line.startswith("| Tokens eth:"):
                # Set flag to capture next line when we get to it
                capture = True
            item.append(line)

def main():
    import sys
    print("============")
    for tokens, item in sorted(list(items(sys.argv[1]))):
        print("".join(item), end="")
        print("============")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For simplicity, I made the generator also perform filtering, though it would be easy to remove items with a lower total on the caller's side if you wanted to make this reusable.

Demo: https://ideone.com/UKuC6C

In fact, I would recommend that you parse this haphazard file format just once, and convert it to a standard format like CSV or JSON for further processing if this is more than a one-off.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions from the `re` module of the standard library you can, for example, split the text into blocks enclosed by the separator, then find the amount of eth in each block, sort and finally filter them.

```
# parameters
total_txt = """from question"""
sorted_file_name = 'sort.txt'
THRESHOLD = 20.
as_dicreasing_order = False

# body
separators = re.finditer('='*12, total_txt)
separators = list(separators)
blocks = map(total_txt.__getitem__, [slice(m1.start(), m2.start()) for m1, m2 in zip(separators, separators[1:])])
amount_block_pairs = [(float(re.search(r'Tokens eth:\n\| (\d*\.\d*)\$', block, re.M).group(1)), block) for block in blocks]
# reverse=False for increasing order, True for the opposite
sorted_blocks = sorted(amount_block_pairs, reverse=as_dicreasing_order) 
filtered_blocks = [block for amount, block in sorted_blocks if amount >= THRESHOLD]

with open(sorted_file_name, 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(''.join(filtered_blocks))
```

Answer (score 0):

One another option is to use python ttp template to parse your data. In the following code, it checks your total values, finds out the value lower than 20.0. Then, the code asks a value to enter which will replace with the `Tokens eth:` which is lower than 20.

```
from ttp import ttp
import json

with open('total.txt') as f:
    data_to_parse = f.read()

ttp_template = '''
| Total: {{total}}$
| {{tokens_eth}}$ {{ignore}}
'''
parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
parser.parse()

# print result in JSON format
results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
#print(results)

#converting str to json. 
result = json.loads(results)

# print(result)

for i in result[0]:
    # print(i)
    if float(i['total']) < 20:
        new_tokens_eth = float(input(f"Total value is {i['total']} lower than 20. Enter a new 'Tokens eth:' value: "))
        if i['tokens_eth'] in data_to_parse:
            data_to_parse = data_to_parse.replace(i['tokens_eth'], str(new_tokens_eth))

print(data_to_parse)
```

See the parsed data:

[image]

See the output after the code is run.

[image]